# Is there a way to show a popup like a "cloud" when you passed your mouse over a textfield in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, mouse, textfield

I'm looking for a way to display a baloon tip when i mouse-over a textfield in Java, for example to guide the user in the way to put some specific data: ID: 0-0000-000 or something like that...

Is there a way to do that, other than jOptionPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`JtextField#setToolTipText(tipText)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29) method for that(note that **JTextField extends JTextComponent which extends JComponent**).

```
String toolTip = "Welcome";
myTextField.setToolTipText(toolTip);
```

Have a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for detailed explanation on using **ToolTips**.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're looking for a way to add a [tooltip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)? Try this:

```
// A textfield with tooltip that provides help text
JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
textfield.setToolTipText("<your help string here>");
```